# Adding picketlink to my pom.xml creates issues

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I have being dealing with this issue since yesterday and I have being able to fix it.

I added this

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketlink-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>${picketlink.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketlink-impl</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>${picketlink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

to my pom.xml and at first i didnt now what was the problem, because sometimes in worked some times it didnt.

So if I add picketlink to my pom.xml (I tried many options from the picktlink quickstarts, and versions), and it runs the first time, but if I recompile it again and try to replace my .war file  I get and error and I have to delete the data/* tmp/* folders and restart my jboss.

This is the error

```
11:42:41,286 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."mapache.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."mapache.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "mapache.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DVFactoryException: DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DTDDVFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DTDDVFactory.getInstance(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.<init>(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.<init>(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.<init>(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.<init>(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.<init>(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.<init>(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.<init>(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaValidatorComponentManager.<init>(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.AbstractXMLSchema.newValidatorHandler(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.9.1-jbossas-2.jar:]
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.<init>(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:51)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.createUnmarshallerHandler(UnmarshallerImpl.java:139)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.getUnmarshallerHandler(UnmarshallerImpl.java:113)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:178)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:174)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:225)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser.unmarshal(ValidationXmlParser.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.ValidationXmlParser.parseValidationXml(ValidationXmlParser.java:78)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getBootstrapConfiguration(ConfigurationImpl.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension.<init>(ValidationExtension.java:93)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.WeldPortableExtensions.tryRegisterExtension(WeldPortableExtensions.java:54)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.loadAttachments(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:120)
        at org.jboss.as.weld.deployment.processors.WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.deploy(WeldPortableExtensionProcessor.java:80)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
        ... 5 more

11:42:41,290 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014613: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"mapache.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"mapache.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"mapache.war\"
    Caused by: org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DVFactoryException: DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory."}}
```

I have to delete those folders i mentioned before and restart wildfly for it to work again.

Comment: I fixed this, I had openid4java, that uses xerces, and just had to remove openid4java

Comment: I think you should also change scope to `provided` because this librares are provided by container (wildfly)